Help understanding what I actually need for grow lights
I would like to start tomato and pepper seedlings indoors.  I know I will need a good light source, but the options are dizzying.  I do not want a specific  item recommended to me, but a general sense of..
What style of LED light would be good to cover a 2ft x 4ft growing area?  How do I evaluate what part of the spectrum I will be getting?  How powerful should the lights be to work well?
As soon as the plants are big enough I will put them outside, so I don't need to support flowering or fruiting plants.

The options are mostly dizzying due to a proliferation of people growing other things under lights and driving the market. If you're not starting them way too soon, a regular old white shop-light fixture will work quite adequately, but if you don't have one (or as many as you need) already it would be nice to know what would be most cost-effective to buy, and to run, for a few months of seedling growth.

I've been starting tomatoes and other plants under shop lights for literally decades, and they work just fine as long as you plant them out when they're not liable to freeze.

I know you said you did not want a specific item recommended but, as Ecnerwal says, a cheap and simple solution is a good answer.
Two banks of twin 48" fluorescents ( 4 tubes total) with grow light tubes should do the job.  You can get these used from recycling or surplus shops as they come out of offices getting a refit.  The ballasts last forever and grow light tubes should be good for three to five years.
The light unit can be suspended on chains to increase the height as the plants grow and most timers will accommodate the amperage used.
This solution works for you because it is cheap, proven and you only need to run it for a few months to start seedlings.  If you were growing lights year round that would mean higher electricity costs and the bigger upfront costs of LED might make sense.
High Pressure Sodium or Halogen lights are going to produce a lot of light and heat and need a lot of power so I don't recommend them.

The ballasts only last quite a while, not forever. Typically 3-6 bulb lives. Some outliers go longer, some less.

@Ecnerwal so, if you buy a used light unit from a recycler that is two thirds used up then it will last for the life of at two bulbs which is six to ten years.  Sounds like good value to me.  I have had light units from recyclers last ten to fifteen years.

If I have shop lights that have been retrofitted with leds instead of fluorescent tubes, will these suffice?

@nuggethead  Sure, the way to tell if they are providing enough light is to observe if the seedlings are stretched out and really tall.  This would indicate not enough light or light too far away.  The key is that you are only using these to start seedlings so pretty much anything will get them growing.

I suggest ignoring the spectrum output when choosing your light. Exactly as you say it is different for each plant, and in my experience hunting down studies to characterize my particular crop usually shows about a 5% gain in efficiency by using a 'matched' spectrum. And then I get a puzzle of finding a light that 'matches'. Its just not relevant in a domestic setting.
If the manufacturer publishes it, you can compare the light's  Photosynthetically_active_radiation (PAR) to another light, but there is not a standard unit for it. I do not always find this published on the cheap units I prefer.
I have personally landed on using LEDs that consume 35 watts per square foot of growing area. So for your 8 square feet, I would want about 280 watts consumed by the LED lighting. This is a really rough estimate- different LEDs turn a watt into different amounts and colors of light - but I find it the most practical approach for domestic scale indoor growing. Do note that many lights publish a wattage that is their 'incandescent equivalent' and means absolutely nothing. You need to know the actual power consumed. For example I just bought a pair of "200 watt" LED panels that actually consume 29.7 watts measured. So they almost produce enough light for 2 square feet of growing space.
I would also consider the form factor of the light. You will want to be able to raise/lower the light if you are growing anything over two inches-ish tall. Some lights make that very easy, and some make that very cumbersome!
